# How can I convert a big matrix to a table?

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I have a .desc file that is used in the read.big.matrix(), from the bigmemory package, to create a big.matrix. How can I open this as a table?

I have tried as.table() and get the error "cannot coerce to a table".

Comment: Not sure what you expected? Can you show it with a standard matrix maybe?

Comment: @F.Privé I expected it to open as a table. It's a kinship matrix, so I've worked with them in .csv and .txt format before. The software that made this one outputs a binary and a .desc, and I am trying to figure out how to open it in table form. I am going to try to go to matrix then to table and see how that goes.

Comment: I don't understand what "table" format to expect for a kinship matrix. You want a matrix? A data frame? A csv?

Comment: @F.Privé Any of them. I tried as.matrix() and got one line of NA's and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a matrix, use

```
bigmemory::attach.big.matrix("yourfile.desc")[]
```

Comment: No problem. Just out of curiosity, which is the package you use to compute the GRM?

Comment: It came from a GWAS package called MVP. I'm not sure what it uses to calculate kinship specifically though.  https://github.com/XiaoleiLiuBio/MVP